# How do I setup Python for RESTApi abilities

Tags: python, rest

I am new to Python development.  I just need to write a simple app that calls our REST API and can test for GET, PUT, POST, DELETE.  I am using Python Dev Tools in Visual Studio 2015.  The first question I have is what process should I be attaching this app to when running so that I can actually see an output of results?  Next question is based on the code below, is there anything I am missing to issue a basic POST request? I have removed my actual URL, username and password, however, I have tested SwaggerUI and I do get a web token back so I have the right URL and credentials.

```
import urllib
import requests


data = {
    'username': 'myUsernameIsHere',
    'password': 'myPasswordIsHere'
    }

urllib.request.urlopen('http://MYURLISINSERTEDHERE', urllib.urlencode(data))

print(data)
```

Comment: You will save yourself a lot of headaches if you use a framework like Flask. Requests is bundled in it too. Take a look: http://flask.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking through documentation here is how I set up my GET and POST request.  I first had to do a POST to our authentication to get back a bearer token.  Once I had that token, I created a local variable to store the token.  Then made any GET request I wanted and passed in the token.  Here is how it looks obviously you would fill in your own username, password, url and token, but you get the idea.

**POST Request - to get my Bearer token**

```
#import requests library for making REST calls
import requests
import json

#specify url
url = 'YOUR URL GOES HERE'

#Create payload that will be passed to API for authentication
payload = {
           #This will be the data that you need to POST to the REST API. 
In my example, in order to get back a web token, I just needed username and password.
               "username": "USERNAME",
               "password": "PASSWORD"
              }

#Fill in headers
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

#Call REST API
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

#Print Response
print(response.text)
```

**GET Request - to get data back while using the Bearer token from above**

```
#import requests library for making REST calls
import requests

#specify url
url = 'YOUR URL GOES HERE'
token = "THIS WAS WHERE I STORED MY TOKEN"

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
#Print Response
print (response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `urllib` unless you need to.

You imported `requests` it's as simple as:

```
payload = {
    'username': 'myUsernameIsHere',
    'password': 'myPasswordIsHere'
}

r = requests.post("http://yourwebsite", data=payload)
```

Depending on the API, you might need to encode the payload to something like JSON instead.

```
import json
r = requests.post("http://yourwebsite", data=json.dumps(payload))
```